# Calculating the number of lines in a file?

Tags: command-line, bash

How would I calculate and display the number of lines and words that are contained in a .sh file?

Answer (score 162):

Use the program `wc`.

- To count the number of lines: `-l`

  ```
    wc -l myfile.sh
  ```
- To count the number of words: `-w`

  ```
    wc -w myfile.sh
  ```

See [`man wc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wc.1posix.html) for more options.

Comment: Be aware that the documentation says: "print the newline counts" when using the `-l` option, so if your file have three lines (two \n), thus, `wc -l myfile.sh` will return 2.

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned by souravc, you can use `wc` for this:

```
$ wc -w statusToFiles.sh 
10 statusToFiles.sh
$ wc -l statusToFiles.sh 
6 statusToFiles.sh
```

To only display the count itself, you can pipe that output to `awk`, like this:

```
$ wc -l statusToFiles.sh | awk '{ print $1 }'
6
```

...or as kos mentioned below:

```
$ < statusToFiles.sh wc -l
6
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use grep command with blank matching string

```
grep "" -c file_path
```

Comment: Why does this is answer not have more upvotes? Is there something fishy about it? It works like a charm for me and the code looks very simple.

Comment: or with non-blank matching string if you want to count non-empty lines `grep -c . file` (The period . matches any single character.)

Comment: @FelixCrazzolara because the `wc -l` command is three times faster

Comment: @Hannibal but grep use frequently and easy to remember

Comment: This worked for me as I was not able to use `wc`

Answer (score 8):

You can also output the entire file with line numbers in front of every line using the command below:

```
cat -n myfile
```

Comment: This is useless for big files (e.g. 250MB), instead it may causing freeze