# Script that rename a folder if the folder is empty

Tags: command-line, scripts, filemanager

This don't work for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to find empty folder in current folder and rename it.

#find empty folder and write it into fef.txt
find . -type d -empty -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | cut -c2- > fef.txt;

#number line of fef.txt
nl_fef=$(cat fef.txt | wc -l);

#rename loop
for i in {1..$nl_fef};
do

# folder path
f=$(pwd);
d=$(cat fef.txt | head -$i | tail -1)
folder_path=$f$d

#rename folder_name to folder_name.empty 
mv "$folder_path" "$folder_path".empty;

done;
```

This is output:

```
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

head: invalid option -- '{'
Try 'head --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Don't just dump code and tell us it doesn't work! You need to explain what it is _supposed_ to do and _how_ it "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because [brace expansion does not accept variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence).

Apart from that there are a lot of strange or "bad" things in your script, e.g.:

- For better performance, put `-maxdepth 1` and `-mindepth 1` as first argument to `find`.
- Why do you cut off the `.` and add `$pwd` instead of just leaving it a relative path ?
- [Use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442914/calculating-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file) `wc -l < fef.txt` instead of this useless use of `cat`.
- [Use `sed` to get line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file/6022431).

But why you don't simply use `find -exec`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name  -empty -exec mv {} {}.empty \;
```

To revert if not empty anymore:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -name "*.empty" -not -empty -exec rename 's/.empty$//' {} +
```

or combined:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d \
  \( -empty -not -name "*.empty" -exec rename 's/$/.empty/' {} + \) \
  -or \( -not -empty -name "*.empty" -exec rename 's/.empty$//' {} + \)
```

This will rename to `.empty` if empty and will remove `.empty` if not empty.